# wp_set_object_terms returns 500 error when called through AJAX function

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, terms

I created dropdowns on the front-end to allow an admin user to change the custom post taxonomy values. On a save button click it runs an AJAX call to a separate PHP file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: template_directory.templateUrl + '/template-parts/tickets/submit-ticket-changes.php',
    data: {
        id: post_id,
        value: changed_value,
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

The variables that are passed are the post id and the new value of the taxonomy as a slug.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$successMessage = 'Ticket [' . $id . '] has been updated';

wp_set_object_terms( $id, array($value), 'ticket_categories' );
echo $successMessage . ' to ' . $value . '!';
```

I have used echo + console log to verify that the two passed variables work. The ID shows as an integer and the value shows as the slug, but when I try to do the set object terms it returns a 500 error to the page.

I have tried with the wp_set_post_terms() function instead. I have tried manually entering the values as opposed to variables( eg. `wp_set_object_terms( 12, array(5), 'ticket_categories' );`). I feel like I've tried everything so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have 500, because wp core is not loaded. Please read how to work with ajax in wp in codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, I was reading through the documentation and could not figure out how to fix this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: you should look at adding a custom JSON API endpoint. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: To expand on @KAGGDesign's comment, here are some examples from the Codex on performing AJAX requests with WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins